# Catch AWS Cloud Watch custom error code from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to send error codes from AWS to Slack.

I've created slack channel and connected between slack and cloud watch.

Some of Metrics messages were sent to slack.

If i make custom error like

```
ret.code=404;   // no api
console.log('404');
```

I can catch on Insight

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
| filter @message like /(?i)(404)/
```

how can I send it to slack? or make metrics?

Or other way to send custom error to slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a CloudWatch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html) using a [custom metric filter that catches 404 errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Counting404Responses.html), and then have that alarm trigger send a message to an SNS topic which triggers a Lambda that pushes the data to slack using a webhook